# Are the sink and washer vented correctly?

Tags: plumbing, sink, washing-machine, drain-waste-vent

[image: Laundry Room Plumbing Diagram]

I want to avoid cutting through the studs supporting the window header above the sink.  Many of the plumbing diagrams I've seen cut through multiple studs.  This layout would only require holes for the 2" washer drain and 1.5" sink vent in one stud, but I'm not sure if it's laid out correctly.  I think I may need a clean out for the washer too, but not sure where.

Comment: I assume from  2" washer drain and 1.5" sink vent - your sink is on the left and your washer drain is in the center pictured as the box?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the piece that loops around your sink?  It's redundant.

You need a P-trap in your washer line to prevent gases from backing up into your washroom

Otherwise, what you have drawn out is fine.  No need for a clean-out.

Comment: it looks like you have them identified in reverse of what the ops picture and statement is:  2" washer drain and 1.5" sink vent - note on the pipes the diameters labeled. Really the op should have labeled what was what.